# Is locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() really needed to monitor or range beacons?

Tags: ios, background, monitoring, ibeacon

I did not get a convincing answer to why startUpdatingLocation should be used to range beacons. Is is required to monitor/range beacons in background or to get notifications when user is already in region and starts monitoring beacons? Came across posts which say this can actually increase the battery consumption. Would like to not call this method it it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**It is not necessary.** I have built dozens of beacon apps and they all  range and monitor beacons just fine without this enabled.

You only need to call that method if you *also* need GPS (or other geo sensor) location updates.

Try it and see!